# How to make a field in a model only exist on a condition met on another field?

Tags: django, models

I'm trying to make it so that only if `MusicPackState.type` equals `loan` will there be 
a reference to the member who is currently loaning it. Am I going about the right way for doing this?

```
class Member(models.Model):
    firstName = models.CharField(max_length = 20)
    lastName = models.CharField(max_length = 20)
    address = models.ForeignKey(models.ForeignKey(Address)
    memberContactInfo = models.ForeignKey(MemberContactInfo)

class MusicPack(models.Model)
    title = models.CharField(max_length = 20)
    composer = models.CharField(max_length = 20)
    arranger = models.CharField(max_length = 20)

class MusicPackState(models.Model)
    TYPES_CHOICES = (
        ('ISSUED', 'Issued'),
        ('LIBRARY', 'Library'),
        ('LOAN', 'Loan'),
        ('ENTERTAINMENTFOLDER', 'Entertainment Folder')
    )
    type = models.CharField(_('Type'), max_length = 20, choices = TYPES_CHOICES)


    def if_loan(self)
        if type == 'Loan'
                member = models.ForeignKey(Member)
```

Comment: You cannot have optional database column. One thing you can do is, have `member` nullable, and show/hide in the view/form based on the `type` value

Comment: Note that the value of `type` will be `'LOAN'`, not `'Loan'`. The second form is only used in the `get_<fieldname>_display()` methods.